# best practice for wallet charge in laravel for booking flights system

Tags: laravel, critical-section

Assume that we want to create a booking flights system that use an external API
we have these steps to get ticket

1. search flights
2. select flights
3. send passenger data
4. if we have enough charge in our wallet **can book ticket**
5. if we don't have ticket go to bank gateway and in callback  if successful payment **charge wallet**  and then send to api to **book ticket**
6. If failed payment we show the error and nothing more need to do

For step 5 i use ATlpay API as a bank gateway , they working with **GET** Callback

I create a database transactions  with these fields

```
Id             |             api_id     |   amount  |             status                         | user_id
Auto Increment | atlpay transaction id |  double   |  Enum('start' , 'failed' , 'success'  )    |  Auth::user()->id

*   default  status is start
```

Its the scenario of sending user to bank Gateway

```
1.create transaction with price and user_id and status= 'start' as a default and return a transaction with id 7
    1.A and set **callback url** for bank like my_site.com/transaction/callback/7

2.post request to bank to get a url 
2.in successful request bank get us an url and atlpay_id like u3873873873873 that is unique
    2.A we save this id to transaction $transaction->api_id  = u3873873873873 ; $transaction->save();

3.redirect user to bank url like ( atlpay.com/transaction/u3873873873873)

4.after bank payment is complete bank redirect to our **callback url**  that set in step 1.A
```

after bank redirect to my_site.com/transaction/callback/7  , I get the $transaction for this user and this transaction id ( in this example is 7) if the transaction status is 'start'

And after then i change the status to failed to other request can't get to this transaction ( But i know that **it's not guaranteed** this requirement! 
I want to find best practice to only one request can achieve this line and other line after that 
//ONLY ONE REQUEST MUST achieve this ++++

```
 $transaction= Auth::user()->transactions()
        ->where('status' , 'start')
        ->where('id' , $id)
        ->first();

    if(!$transaction)
        dd("You are not The owner");

//ONLY ONE REQUEST MUST achieve this ++++

    $transaction->status = 'failed';
    $transaction->save();

    $api_url = 'transactions/'.$transaction->api_id;
    $payment_data  = $this->get_transaction_payment_data($api_url);

    if(is_success_payment($payment_data )
       $this->charge_wallet($payment_data->price);
```

And my charge_wallet function is

```
   public function charge_wallet($price)
{
    Wallet::where('user_id' , Auth::user()->id)->increment('amount', $price );
    return true;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for achieve the critical section , I don't know its okay or not! 
I use a second table for generate key

```
Table:transaction_keys
transaction_id  , key ( unique)  , user_id
```

I want to create only one **key** for **each transaction**  and insert on  **database** and in current **session** .( for each transaction only one key can be generated  , another request denied by mysql! ) the primary key of the table is transaction_id

```
public function success_transaction($transaction , $price)
{

    $transaction->status = 'success';
    $transaction->save();
    $user_key  = $this->create_user_key( $transaction);

    if($this->is_valid_user_key($user_key)){
        $this->charge_wallet($price);

    }else{
        dd($user_key);
        //Log or smth else
    }




}


public function is_valid_user_key($user_key)
{
    return $user_key['status'] == 'success';
}


public function create_user_key($transaction)
{

    try{

        $int1 = rand(30,40);
        $int2 = rand(40,50);
        $unique_id = Str::random($int1) . uniqid() . Str::random($int2);

        $user_key  = new UserKey();
        $user_key->transaction_id = $transaction->id;
        $user_key->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $user_key->user_key = $unique_id;
        $user_key->save();

        request()->session()->forget('user_key' );
        request()->session()->put('user_key' , $user_key);
        $end_data['status'] = 'success';
        $end_data['key'] = $unique_id;
        return $end_data;


    }catch (\Exception $exception){
        dd($exception);
        $end_data['status'] = 'error';

        return $end_data;
        //Log or smth else

    }

}
```